# Equivalent of android's styles.xml in Xcode

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, uifont

I am trying to set a custom font to all labels in Xcode storyboard. Storyboard comprises of labels in multiple view controllers. I do not have any outlets for these labels. In android, it's done through styles.xml but unable to find an equivalent for the same in iOS. 
I tried this code too:

```
  struct FontName {
    static let semiBold = "SourceSansPro-SemiBold"
}

extension UIFont {

    class func mySemiBoldFont() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: FontName.semiBold, size: 20)!
    }

}
```

The problem is that I want to make it in such a way that I can set `mySemiBoldFont` in storyboard's font and incase of any size changes, I just replace it to new value instead of `20` and it gets applied everywhere.

Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: There are no exact equivalent of android's styles.xml. What you have here is probably the closest you can get. Just don't do it in the storyboard, set all your fonts with code.

Comment: I will have to make outlets of each label or an outletconnection unnecessarily for that

Comment: Isn't there any better approach?

Comment: I personally don't find storyboard that useful a tool for setting the styles of UI elements. What's wrong with adding outlets? Or just not use storyboards at all and write everything in code.

Comment: @Dia you don't have to add outlets just to change the font. Check my answer, I hope it will be useful.

Comment: @Sweeper Do you have any example? Will size based on Screen Width? How to set font Bold, Regular with different sizes?.. Do i have to do by programmatically? Is there any common place to do?

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom font from storyboard you should do the following things:

First, be sure to add the font file to your project (drag it into your project) and set its target, or it will not work.

1. Open info.plist
2. Add row
3. Type "Fonts provided by application". It should autocomplete.
4. Expand the row and add an element (item 0)
5. Set item 0 type to "String" and value is your exact font name (Es. MyFont.ttc/ttf, try avoid spaces in name)

Now you should be able to use the fonts both programmatically and from storyboard.
To use it from storyboard, select the label, as font set custom type and choose the family, Check the image as example.

> ***NOTE:*** Obviously, you have to set the font manually for each label you add to storyboard.
>   There's no way to change it one time and have all label fonts changed.

[image: Info.plist example with two fonts]
Info.plist example with two fonts

[image: I created a directory and I dragged fonts in it]

I created a directory and I dragged fonts in it

[image: Be sure this is checked for each font]

Be sure this is checked for each font

[image: Set font from storyboard]

Set Font from storyboard example

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking for a way to set fonts to multiple labels spread over various view controllers at once

Comment: As I said,  there's no way to do it with UILabel. All you can try is to create a subclass of UILabel, set a default font and use the new class for all your label